# SQL issue: Inserting values into one clumn, same amount of EMPTY values in every other column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've tried searching a resolution for my issue below, however, results come back with "HOW" to insert null values to a column, which is what I'm trying to prevent. Please educate me.

When I insert values into ONE column, every other column gets the same amount of records added, but they are EMPTY!! What?!?!?

```
    INSERT INTO departments(`Account Executive 3`) VALUES('test'),('test2');
    Query OK, 2 rows affected
```

This is the result on that column:

```
    SELECT `Account Executive 3` FROM departments;
    +---------------------+
    | Account Executive 3 |
    +---------------------+
    | test                |
    | test2               |
```

Great! Just what I wanted. This is what I DO NOT want:

```
    SELECT `Account Executive 2` FROM departments;
    +---------------------+
    | Account Executive 2 |
    +---------------------+
    |                     |
    |                     |
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why are X-amount of empty rows appending to every other column??

Comment: It`s normal behaviour for SQL.

Comment: :O  ugh! Okay,...time to find a workaround then on my query

Comment: In sql you are inserting rows,even when you insert in one column only.

Comment: In other words,...I should have done some more research. Still learning here. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you have 5 columns, and insert a new one with only one column value, what would you expect to happen to the other four columns? Do you think the table magically changes to only have one column and removes the other four? You're inserting a new **row**, which has an entry for every one of the columns contained in the row whether it has a value or not. Think of an Excel spreadsheet - when you insert a new row and put something into `A1`, you don't just get one single cell that's isolated. You get a whole new row, all the way across the width of the sheet.

Comment: Didn't even think of it that way. Thanks. Just put on the Noob hat!

Comment: I've posted an answer to try and make it clear what happens, and why it does so. Hopefully it will help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert into the table, you're inserting a new **row** of data; it includes every column in the table, whether it gets a value or not.

Think of an Excel spreadsheet. When you insert a new row and put a value in cell `A1`, you don't end up with just a single cell; the row extends all the way across the sheet, whether you put values in just cell `A1` or not.

To illustrate, imagine you have a table (`Tbl`) with three columns, and a single row:

```
COL_A    COL_B    COL_C
=====    =====    =====
1        Test     123
```

If you `INSERT INTO Tbl (COL_A) VALUES (2)`, you'd now have:

```
COL_A    COL_B    COL_C
=====    =====    =====
1        Test     123
2
```

Another `INSERT INTO Tbl (COL_A, COL_C) VALUES (3, 234)` results in:

```
COL_A    COL_B    COL_C
=====    =====    =====
1        Test     123
2        
3                 234
```

The new empty columns actually contain `NULL`; I've left them blank to more clearly demonstrate. The last would actually look more like

```
COL_A    COL_B    COL_C
=====    =====    =====
1        Test     123
2        NULL     NULL   
3        NULL     234
```

Comment: Got it. I've updated my query accordingly to not display blank / empty / NULL rows. Thanks!